# Google Maps tool for accurately positioning image overlay?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, overlay

I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

I have a Google Map that loads markers from an XML file, along with various other map elements, works great. However I now need to overlay a PNG image onto the map.

I have tried for hours to correctly align the PNG over the top of the site but just cannot find the exact two co-ordinates I need (south-west and north-east). Is there a tool for doing this? Ideally upload the image and drag the corners to fit, and it outputs the two co-ordinates (lat/lng) you need?

I have tried using this tool: http://overlay-tiler.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/upload.html - but it has three contact points.

I have also tried using this tool: http://www.birdtheme.org/useful/customoverlay.html - but you cannot resize the image once uploaded to the map and you get one chance at clicking the south-west marker!

I can also use Google Earth to align the PNG perfectly, but I can't see a way of outputting the lat/lng points.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear whether upload/drag capability is for development purposes or as an end user feature?

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot I would think of it as a once off end user feature like align the picture once and then save the required data and just show the image @ that rotation or scale each time

Comment: Re "use Google Earth to align the PNG perfectly, but I can't see a way of outputting the lat/lng points." I believe you output as KML, and extract the numbers from that. See Ground Overlays in Keyhole Markup Language tutorial: https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut?hl=it

Answer (score 28):

Heres a working example of André Dion's explanation.

http://jsfiddle.net/4cWCW/3/

```
var overlay;

DebugOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.743388,-74.007592)
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  var swBound = new google.maps.LatLng(40.73660837340877, -74.01852328);
  var neBound = new google.maps.LatLng(40.75214181, -73.99661518216243);
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(swBound, neBound);

   console.log(map);
  var srcImage = 'http://robincwillis.com/top/splash/04.jpg';

  overlay = new DebugOverlay(bounds, srcImage, map);

  var markerA = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: swBound,
            map: map,
            draggable:true
        });

    var markerB = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: neBound,
        map: map,
        draggable:true
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(markerA,'drag',function(){

        var newPointA = markerA.getPosition();
        var newPointB = markerB.getPosition();
        var newBounds =  new google.maps.LatLngBounds(newPointA, newPointB);
        overlay.updateBounds(newBounds);
    });

  google.maps.event.addListener(markerB,'drag',function(){

      var newPointA = markerA.getPosition();
      var newPointB = markerB.getPosition();
      var newBounds =  new google.maps.LatLngBounds(newPointA, newPointB);
      overlay.updateBounds(newBounds);
  });

    google.maps.event.addListener(markerA, 'dragend', function () {

        var newPointA = markerA.getPosition();
        var newPointB = markerB.getPosition();
        console.log("point1"+ newPointA);
        console.log("point2"+ newPointB);
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(markerB, 'dragend', function () {
        var newPointA = markerA.getPosition();
        var newPointB = markerB.getPosition();
        console.log("point1"+ newPointA);
        console.log("point2"+ newPointB);
    });

}

function DebugOverlay(bounds, image, map) {

  this.bounds_ = bounds;
  this.image_ = image;
  this.map_ = map;
  this.div_ = null;
  this.setMap(map);
}

DebugOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function() {

  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.style.borderStyle = 'none';
  div.style.borderWidth = '0px';
  div.style.position = 'absolute';
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = this.image_;
  img.style.width = '100%';
  img.style.height = '100%';
  img.style.opacity = '0.5';
  img.style.position = 'absolute';
  div.appendChild(img);
  this.div_ = div;
  var panes = this.getPanes();
  panes.overlayLayer.appendChild(div);
};

DebugOverlay.prototype.draw = function() {
  var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();
  var sw = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getSouthWest());
  var ne = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getNorthEast());
  var div = this.div_;
  div.style.left = sw.x + 'px';
  div.style.top = ne.y + 'px';
  div.style.width = (ne.x - sw.x) + 'px';
  div.style.height = (sw.y - ne.y) + 'px';
};


DebugOverlay.prototype.updateBounds = function(bounds){
    this.bounds_ = bounds;
    this.draw();
};

DebugOverlay.prototype.onRemove = function() {
  this.div_.parentNode.removeChild(this.div_);
  this.div_ = null;
};

initialize();
```

Comment: Finnaly what I was looking for ! But there is a difference of coordinates between OSM and google map... I need the same with OSM..

Comment: This is great thanks

Comment: This helped me a lot!!

Answer (score 9):

I had to solve this exact problem for a client not long ago. My solution was to simply create two markers; one at each `LatLng` for the overlay's `LatLngBounds` that, when moved, would update the overlay and log the `LatLndBounds` to the `console` for me to reference. I also added reticules (vertical and horizontal lines) that are shown when dragging a marker so it was easier to visually position the overlay.

I cannot share the code from the solution with you, but it involves working with an `OverlayView` in order to convert `LatLng` coordinates to and from pixels via [`MapCanvasProjection`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapCanvasProjection).

Like you, we didn't need this functionality for end-users so I added a "authoring mode" that's toggled by providing a `debug` parameter to the solution's query string.

Comment: Yea i also have a mode that is only triggered once and only if a user has enough permission to perform the action 

So to pick your brain a small bit 
You Create the bottom left marker
Then the user adds the top right marker
User sees that the image is like 3 / 10 / 20 degrees off so they drag the bottom left marker upwards and then you just redraw the image after that

Comment: By moving either NE or SW markers, you skew the image overlay. I forgot to mention that as a prerequisite, the image used for the overlay needs to be in the same orientation as the map (i.e., the top of the image is North).

Comment: are you maybe the same person that built [thannmap on appspot](http://thannmap.appspot.com/) ? 
Also did you have to do much Trig in this Solution?

I am also wondering if building this solution would be similar to this [google/overlays#CustomOverlays](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#CustomOverlays) solution ? exept you just replace the hard coded co-ords of the bot left / top right with your user specified markers co-ords ?

Comment: No, that wasn't me. My solution doesn't involve any trigonometry, though it did subclass `google.maps.CustomOverlay`.

Comment: i did you what did but like when you put the NE marker Lower than the SW marker the image appears to be bellow the bounding box :( 
[something like this](http://overlay-tiler.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/edit.html?overlay=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fintl%2Fen_com%2Fimages%2Fsrpr%2Flogo3w.png&lat=-34.0391543474887&lng=23.042416499999945&z=11) would be like amazing

Answer (score 2):

I like to use the one located here:

http://googlemapsapi.blogspot.com/2007/05/v280-making-image-overlays-easy-with.html

It's far from ideal, and it generates Google Maps version 2 API code, but you can still use the logitude/latitude coordinates.