# Show simple image on Google Map API

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I want to show a simple image on my map like a rectangle with the Top left corner and the Bottom right corner.
To be able to do the following:
[image]
With the "green part" being an png image (So a rectangle, with transparent and visible parts).

How can i perform that using the Google Map API ? I didn't find the resource on the documentation.

Thanks

Comment: Reword your question? You say rectangle but your png shows a polygon like example. Google maps has custom controls which let you embed html/css on the map otherwise its standard content

Comment: I said rectangle cause the green is part of a square image but with transparent part (Like on png image). I will edit the question. Thanks

Comment: Please tell me the reason when some of you downvote the post, so i can improve myself. If this is because i show no example of my work, it's because i found nothing at all. Already worked with rectangle and marker but that's not the subject here. Thanks

Comment: I didnt down vote, others did.. its because it made no sense.. google polygon for google maps

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer, you need to place your image with two marker.
Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20254806/5384382